# How to make django urls dynamic

Tags: django, url

I want to make my urls dynamic. So far the problem occurs when any of the url is not listed among these urls the page shows not found 404 error.

For eg:
If i want to access the /dashboard i can easily do it because it is listed. Now i want to access follow-up tab after that which is in my sidebar /dashboard/follow-up i can do that too but when i want to access another tab lets say table so the url will be /dashboard/follow-up/table it will not be accessed. 
I know it is not possible to add all possible combinations of URL because there would be many.
I am new to django. Please someone guide me how to solve the problem. I have provided my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
    path('dashboard/notifications', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='notifications.html'), name='notifications'),
    path('dashboard/Login_request', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='Login_request.html'), name='Login_request'),
    path('dashboard/follow-up/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='follow-up.html'), name='follow-up'),
    path('accounts/password_change/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='password_change'), name='password_change'),
    path('accounts/password_change/done/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='password_change_done'), name='password_change_done'),
    path('dashboard/settings/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='settings.html'), name='settings'),
    path('dashboard/', views.chart, name='dashboard'),
    path('table/', views.offense, name='table'),
    path('dashboard/user/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='user.html'), name='user'),


]
```

Comment: You can add URL parameters for that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#example please remove the all caps in the question. For a `*nix` user, this is really considered "very rude" language.

Comment: All caps is also much harder to read. Rather use emphasis or bold text in future.

Comment: I am sorry for all caps

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can you give me an example for a path? i can not understand which syntax do i have to use.